# Why can't I connect to a Minecraft lan?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

Coming home for Christmas break, my little brother wants to play some minecraft with me, and I finally obliged. My laptop is wireless on the network, and his old family computer is wired, with no wireless connection available. When I try to host the lan server, he can't see it, but when he hosts the server, I can see it. Here's the problem though. Whenever I try to connect to his lan server, it times out, with the error of unable to connect. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: **Welcome to Arqade, Andrew!** Did the above link help you? It seems both questions are asking the same.

Answer (score -3):

try using a different computer to help or turn of both computers then turn on one then turn on the lan option in the in game menu and turn on the other computer and try to join

Comment: Could you please add some info to your answer? It's kinda poor now, as it contains a single sentence (or not even that). Thanks!